# Cannot install tidymodels package

Tags: r

I am not too sure why the tidymodels package is not installing for me, can someone help me with this?

https://gyazo.com/317ade9f7f4b01451e7ef3f91ec4515f

Comment: It seems that you have some old versions of the dependencies, which may need to be updated

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

From Start, go to R and open RGui. Type `install.packages("tidymodels")`. This should work. You will probably need to select the cran location (closest to you). If this does not  work, uninstall and then reinstall R and then follow the above steps. Close RGui and do not save workspace image.